# JasperReport parameters works in iReport but fails on JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have a report created in iReport.  Have a parameter set with isForPrompting="true".  When I go and test it with preview, everything works.

```
Parameter: Symbol
SQL Query: select * from "table" where "column" = $P{Symbol}  -- I'm using Postgres.
```

Then I use Repository Navigator to upload it to the server. The server returns "no pages"  Any thoughts.  I've verified that the report work in both iReport and JasperServer if parameter is removed and the value is hard coded into to the sql query like below.

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select * from "tablename" where "column" = 'testsymbol']]>
</queryString>
```

Comment: Did you check the parameter `Symbol` (with help of textField, for example)?

Comment: Terrible... how come iReport does not have a concept of input control??? To me, whatever you have in iReport should be promote-able directly to the JasperServer.  If that means setting up Input Control in iReport, so be it!  This has been very frustrating. Arggg.

Comment: @sam so does that mean you figured it out? If so you can add an answer to your own question and mark it or answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it was the input control.  It's working now... thanks @precose!!!