# JasperReports parameters works in iReport but fails on JasperReports Server (II)

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a very similar problem to the one described at [[JasperReport parameters works in iReport but fails on JasperServer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459409/jasperreport-parameters-works-in-ireport-but-fails-on-jasperserver) post.

The report works properly within the *iReport* environment using *Preview* option but fails within *JasperReports Server*

The comments suggest that *iReport* does not create the *InputControl* within *JR Server*. So I verified that the server contained the proper *InputControl* (that apparently solved their issue).

The input control called *sk serial selection* :

```
ID: ic_sk_serial
Name: sk serial selection
Type: Single Select Query
Mandatory: false
Read Only: false
Visible: true
Query resource: 
    From repository (pointing to *q_sk_serial* see below)
Value and Visible columns:
    Value column: id
    Visible query columns: serialnr
```

The input control query called *q_sk_serial* (populate the inpute control with a list of alphanumeric serial numbers, items are unique):

```
select id,serialnr from "public"."serials" order by serialnr;
```

The parameter name:

```
ic_sk_serial
```

The report query:

```
select * from "public"."datas" datas where datas."serialnr" like $P{ic_sk_serial}
```

In my case, input control seems to work properly in both environments (within *iReport* preview and *JasperServer*): I populate a list of items coming from the same database; I see that *dropdownlist* as expected within *iReport* but also on with *JR Server*.

Within *iReport*, the drop-down list returns the correct selected value in a report parameter which lead to the correct report. In *JasperReports Server* I only get a *"The report is empty"* message. So I tend to think the report parameter is not properly passed through within *JasperServer*.

Hardcoding the "Input control" output value, shows expected report.

**Side note**: I am using *iReport 4.7.1* in compatibility mode with *JasperReports Server 4.5.0*.

I would be glad to hear if anybody ran into the same problem?

How can I debug further the report execution in *JR Server*?

Is compatibility mode susceptible to cause that issue?

What about the input parameter type? I use a query that return a *string*. However my input data type is *text* (closest match to string). My parameter type is *java.lang.string*. Does this make sense?

Comment: "input control seems to work properly in both environments" Input controls do not exist in iReport. Therefore it's not clear what you meant by this.

Comment: You have not given any indication about whether you see errors. If you do, what errors do you see? Maybe start with Tomcat's catalina.out log file.

Comment: @mdahlman:  

About input control: In iReport you can add an Input Control resource in the repository (right click on any folder) that is what I did. You also have the same possibility from the JasperReport Server web interface. Both are working for me: The input control is created and appearing on screen with the proper content.  

About the error: I get only the message "The report is empty". However hardcoding the selected value returns the data I expect.

Comment: TocToc, have you defined these input controls as parameters in your report within iReport? When you right-click and add the input controls in the repository, you are actually adding them to JasperReports Server, not to iReport.

Comment: I see. Yes, you can create the input control using JRS or iR. In either case it exists in JRS. And clearly it's not working. Does the parameter match (case sensitive) the input control? Post your parameterized query.

Comment: @Lisa : Good suggestion, but yes, I defined the parameter and it has the same name (case sensitive wise) than the input control id. I guess that if it was not the case, the report would not work in the preview.

Comment: @mdahlman: See post above, yes it is case matching.

Comment: Post your parameterized query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that is a simple bug:

I just found out that:

```
value column: id
```

Should be

```
value column: serialnr
```

Still, I do not understand why the report was working in preview mode? Such big mistake should fail on preview no?

In anycase thanks to everybody to lead to my mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, there are two types of parameter within a jasper report including: Report parameter and Dataset Paramter.

Firstly, you must create both parameters and then map the one of Dataset to the one of Report.

I encountered the same problem to you thus that resolved my case.